# SQL DELETE from two tables in the same statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I will delete data from 2 tables. I will do it as follow:

```
 DELETE FROM dc_mail_users u, dc_mail_user_data d WHERE u.i_id_pk = 3 AND d.i_id_ut = u.i_id_pk
```

But this will return a SQL syntax error. How can I fix this whit the SQL AS statement? Just like the example below.

```
SELECT first_name.last_name AS name WHERE name="John Doe"
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*SQL ASS*"?

Comment: I think he's referring to MySQL: It's ass. You should try SQL Server. `</troll>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delete u, d
FROM dc_mail_users u
join dc_mail_user_data d
on d.i_id_ut = u.i_id_pk
and u.i_id_pk = 3
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DELETE u, d
FROM dc_mail_users u
INNER JOIN dc_mail_user_data d
    ON d.i_id_ut = u.i_id_pk
WHERE u.i_id_pk = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Your original statement would also be correct If you add the alias of the tables, an example [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7990/6)